# Trying to get my discord.js bot to mention a user

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have recently been trying to figure out how to get my `discord.js` bot to welcome new users by tagging them in a message, but it just comes out as `@user` *with their discriminator*. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
    client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  let guild = member.guild;
  let memberTag = member.user.tag;
  if(guild.systemChannel){
    guild.systemChannel.send("@" + memberTag + "  has joined the server!")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my personal experience, I've always used the global mentioning method, using `<@id-of-the-user>`. If this is the method you'd like to try, change 
`guild.systemChannel.send("@" + memberTag + "  has joined the server!")` with `guild.systemChannel.send("<@" + member.id + "> has joined the server!")`.